# Unique prime factorization

Tags: soft-question, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

We all know that $$15=3 \times 5$$

And $$15 =(-3) \times(-5)$$

Since $3 \neq -3$ and $5 \neq -5$ , we have two different prime factorizations !

Is this wrong ?

If this is wrong , then there are **no negative primes** !

Comment: Primes are defined as integers greater than or equal to two that are only divisible by positive integers $1$ and themself.

Comment: When properly stated, and there is unique factorization, the uniqueness is only up to multiplication by a unit in the ring. In the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, the units are $\pm 1$. The factorization of a natural number greater than one as a product of prime positive integers is absolutely unique ( but $\mathbb{N}$ is no longer a ring). In the Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, which has unique factorization, the units are $\pm 1, \pm i$.

Comment: It depends on the definition of primes that you use.

1) $p$ is prime if $p>0$ and it has exactly the two divisors $1,p$.

2) $p$ is prime if $p$ and it has exactly the four divisors $1,p,-1,-p$.

For example, for Def2, Fundamental Therorem claims that every integer different for 0, 1 and -1 has a unique prime factorization unless order and sign.

Comment: This is the kind of question I personally find extremely uninteresting. It's just a minor issue with definitions that gets in the way of more interesting/important ideas.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/negative_primes.html), [here (math.SE)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002459/do-we-have-negative-prime-numbers) and [here (math.SE)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459996/can-prime-numbers-be-negative)